# How to write json post in this given sample CURL module

Tags: php

i am trying to implement interswitchng.com api. following code is generated from postman's generate code features.  When i try to change following status value with dynamic value using php then it shows some error. i think i do some mistake in CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.  So can you suggest me that how can i write this array in CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS ?

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://sandbox.interswitchng.com/api/v1/quickteller/fundsTransfer",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\r\n  \"mac\": \"8285b03723393d92c30b31474689bc835e448a34345324339e1aef2d0a1a03a438f934a177e0515459e0b6eb6c0c7f3d9a9e26ec3e4447a664343455\",\r\n  \"beneficiary\": {\r\n    \"lastname\": \"Anari\",\r\n    \"othernames\": \"Sammy\"\r\n  },\r\n  \"initiatingEntityCode\": \"XXT\",\r\n  \"initiation\": {\r\n    \"amount\": \"100000\",\r\n    \"channel\": \"7\",\r\n    \"currencyCode\": \"566\",\r\n    \"paymentMethodCode\": \"CA\"\r\n  },\r\n  \"sender\": {\r\n    \"email\": \"simon.mokhele@hellogroup.co.za\",\r\n    \"lastname\": \"Testing\",\r\n    \"othernames\": \"Test\",\r\n    \"phone\": \"0732246413\"\r\n  },\r\n  \"termination\": {\r\n    \"accountReceivable\": {\r\n      \"accountNumber\": \"0014261063\",\r\n      \"accountType\": \"10\"\r\n    },\r\n    \"amount\": \"100000\",\r\n    \"countryCode\": \"NG\",\r\n    \"currencyCode\": \"566\",\r\n    \"entityCode\": \"058\",\r\n    \"paymentMethodCode\": \"AC\"\r\n  },\r\n  \"transferCode\": \"27205265080\"\r\n}",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "authorization: InterswitchAuth SUtJQUI2MzQ0OTlFQjk434adsfdfsdf23zNjkzQTcyODRDQ0EzNDY=",
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "content-type: text/html",
    "nonce: 6fb704016f989a763453456347777",
    "signature: +GWrb0434543345gg=",
    "signaturemethod: SHA1",
    "terminalid: 2vXP0434",
    "timestamp: 3343424"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

If i try to use following sentence, then it does not seem proper (i think).

```
 CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($data['postdata']),
```

Above $data has been send using following code :

```
$postdata=array( "mac"=>"$maccode", "beneficiary"=>array("lastname"=>"$receiverlastname","othernames"=>"$receiverothernames"), "initiatingEntityCode"=>"$InstitutionCode", "initiation"=>array( "amount"=>"$initiation_amount", "channel"=>"7", "initiation_currencyCode"=>"556", "initiation_paymentMethodCode"=>"$initiation_paymentMethodCode" ), "sender"=>array("email"=>"$senderemail","lastname"=>"$senderlastname","othernames"=>"$senderothername","phone"=>"$senderphone"), "termination"=>        array(
       "accountReceivable"=>array("accountNumber"=>"0014261063","accountType"=>"10"),
       "amount"=>"$to_amount",
       "countryCode"=>"$to_countryCode",
       "currencyCode"=>"$to_currencyCode",
       "entityCode"=>"$to_entityCode",
       "paymentMethodCode"=>"$to_paymentMethodCode"
       ), "transferCode"=>"$transferCode" );

$data=array("url"=>"$url", "header"=>array("Authorization"=>"InterswitchAuth $Authorization","Signature"=>"$signature","Nonce"=>"$Nonce","Timestamp"=>"$timestamp","SignatureMethod"=>"SHA1","TerminalId"=>"2vXP0434"), "postdata"=>$postdata );
```